# How can I see which version of map data I have in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: debian, openstreetmap, osmosis

I have built an OSM tile server on Debian. I would like to know how could I see the map version? In fact, I would like to verify if the map data is updated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no "map version", the map is updated continuously. Have you set up automatic updates as described in the *Updating* section [here](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running `openstreetmap-tiles-update-expire`, check `/var/log/tile/run.log`: it should contain results of each update. File `/var/lib/mod_tile/.osmosis/state.txt` should contain a timestamp of the last update.

The osm2pgsql database does not contain timestamps, so you cannot check whether you have the latest data. All you can do is map something from aerial imagery (please do not add bogus objects!), wait for couple minutes and check that changes were drawn on your tiles. To check tile update time, add `/status` to its URL: e.g. `http://localhost/tiles/0/0/0.png/status`. To force tile update, use `/dirty` instead, and wait.

Answer (score 0):

As shown at the end of [this tutorial](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server/), browse to `http://yourserveraddress/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png` to confirm your tile server is serving tiles.

Then, to create a visible "slippy map", you could use the instructions in [this tutorial](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/), i.e. you could use the Leaflet or OpenLayers javascript libraries.

Comment: Hi, thank. In fact, I have already my "slippy map" in my browser. After that, I followed [this tutorial](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/) to keep the tile server up to date with the latest data. So what I really wanna know is how to make sure this step is well done, the map data is updated automatically. Some thing I can do with Postgres?

Comment: OK - it would be good if you could edit your question to be a bit clearer. When you ask "How can I see the map version", I interpret that as "How can I see it rendered as a map" not "How can I see which version of the map I have". Maybe use that latter phrase?